# Flex 4.6: Mobile Flex Application with SWFLoader loading an SWF created with pdf2swf; Click events?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, swfloader, pdf2swf

I am creating a mobile application with Flash builder 4.6.

I am running Windows 7, and compiled SWFTools 0.9.2 using Cygwin.

I have a PDF with an inner-link, and converted it to SWF using:

`pdf2swf.exe test.pdf -f -T 9 -t -s storeallcharacters -s linknameurl -s internallinkfunction=true -s insertstop -o test.swf`.

> SWFLoader disregards the stops (and the button clicks), and loops through the pages Ad infinitum. This isn't an issue by itself, but it suggests SWFLoader deletes/disregards code inside the SWF....

So this means I can forget about catching `TextEvent.LINK` events , (or does it)?

Ideally, I'd want to "pass the events back" to the inner SWF, but, just the ability to catch them, with some payload attached, would do.

Is this somehow possible? Maybe using different loaders, or different conversion tools?

Comment: Adding some sample code on how you load the swf in your stage/application may help.